# C# - Detect Proxy Type (HTTP/Socks4/Socks4a/Socks5)

Tags: c#, proxy

Is it possible to detect the proxy type, preferably without having to do any requests, possibly by examining common proxy ports.

If not, is there a way to make a request and from the request response cross match the type?

My current logic is that proxy types work like the following, though im unsure how accurate it is.

```
if (proxyPort > 1080 && proxyPort != 10200 && proxyPort != 8085 && proxyPort != 8080) pt = ProxyType.Socks5;
if (proxyPort == 1080 || proxyPort == 10200) pt = ProxyType.Socks4;
```